# User GPO - Site to Zone Assignment List (User Policy) is not being applied correctly to Windows 10

Tags: active-directory, gpo

I have a User GPO set that edits Trusted Sites within IE. This is working correctly for our users on Win7. However, the same policy is not working correctly for the same user on Win10. Does anybody have an idea as to why this may be?

Answer (score 2):

We were able to find the GPO that was causing this issue and get it corrected. Unfortunately, I don't have the rep to attach photos. I believe the GPO was called "Security Zones: Do not allow users to add/delete sites". Thanks for your help!